# Freshdesk OAuth SSO: Freshdesk Login Page Doesn't Ping My Auth Page?

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, single-sign-on, freshdesk

I'm trying to connect to Freshdesk using OAuth 2.0, for single sign-on from my app. My app is serving as it's own OAuth identity provider. I've set up my Authorization url on Freshdesk -- let's call it `https://www.myWebApp.com/auth`:

[image: auth url set on freshdesk]

So now for testing purposes I go to the URL that Freshdesk support provided for a user to initiate the single sign-on process:

> https://myWebApp.freshdesk.com/login/normal

...and I see a nice sso-style login screen:

[image: login dialog]

I enter a correct email and password for one of my site users and click "Login".

Now in the Chrome network tab, I would **expect** to see Freshdesk trying to ping my Authorization URL. But I don't. I see this:

[image: network tab]

When loaded, my auth page (`https://myWebApp.com/auth`) pings my server, which issues a `console.log()` message, and my server logs show no such console log message -- so Freshdesk doesn't seem to be pinging my auth page at all.

What is keeping Freshdesk from pinging my auth page as it should?

Comment: On that login screen do you see another  button to log in via SSO?

Comment: I do not. The image in my post shows the entire login dialog.

Comment: I am really struggling to get SSO working on my side - did you ever get your SSO sorted?

Comment: I have got it going my side  so if you are still working on this let me know and I'll try help out.

Comment: Hey @MhluziBhaka I am totally still trying to get this going and would really appreciate the help!

Comment: Oki, am composing an answer - but just for interest, what are you using for the oauth? Are you writing it yourself or using something like laravel-passport? Also, are the users you want to have log into freshdesk agents or contacts?

Comment: Awesome! I'm writing it myself, and my app is also it's own OAuth identity provider. Please let me know if I can provide any additional info!

Comment: Cool, are the users you want to have log into freshdesk agents or contacts?

Comment: They are contacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a fair bit here that you have in place already but I am just adding it in for completeness.

Logged into the backend and on the security page for contacts

```
 https://stackoverflow.myfreshworks.com/security/contacts 
 [stackoverflow == your site :) ]
```

you will have to create a Custom Policy if you don't have one in place already (this is different to the one for Agents)

[image: custom policy for contacts]

And for that configure your SSO with Oauth 2.0

[image: SSO with Oauth 2.0]

Then , if you have at least one SSO configured your login (at https://stackoverflow.freshdesk.com/support/login ) should look like this:

[image: freshdesk login]

Where (1) now appears. That will be the link to ping your server via the urls you set up for the SSO:

If you only have one SSO set up for your contacts that link (1) should complete the sign-in process directly and then you should end up logged into Freshdesk as the specific contact.

If you had two SSO options set up; for example:

[image: multiple SSO options]

..when you clicked the link (1) on the https://stackoverflow.freshdesk.com/support/login page, you should then be redirected to a page with those two options:

[image: SSO option page]

The url for that page is something like (parameters will be different for you):

```
https://stackoverflow.myfreshworks.com/login
?redirect_uri=https://stackoverflow.freshdesk.com/freshid/customer_authorize_callback
&client_id=14416083630394368&slug=6117145232763
```

I am imagining you could use that as a direct link to the portal on your main site.

If you only have one SSO option set up you should be able to navigate directly to the link as above and then see :

[image]

which is probably what you are aiming for.

I changed the name of that button (Sign in with contacts SSO) just to be sure I was using the right one and to differentiate from the login for agents. You can change the text under the Advanced Options when configuring the SSO:

[image: Advanced options]

Hope this helps you along the way - if you have any other questions on this post them as comments.

Comment: I can't wait to work through this! I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: This is helping a lot! Here's a question. When the user clicks the link (1) in your illustration, Freshdesk pings the auth endpoint on my server. At that point, how can my server tell which user is trying to log into Freshdesk? Am I supposed to encode a user id in the link my user clicks on my site, that brings him or her to the Freshdesk page where link (1) is?

Comment: I see that when my app sends my user to the FreshDesk login page, my app includes a `state` variable.  And, when the use cicks link (1), that same `state` data comes back to my server. 

Do I need to store the user id in the `state` data, perhaps encrypted, so that when the user clicks link (1), my server can see what user it is?

Comment: Okay I've been studying up and I see that `state` is a random string. When it comes back from FreshDesk the client or server can check to see if it's legit.  If I want the server to do it, it appears I first need to mutate the db to store the `state` value and name the associated user.

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit of a tap dance. You would be sending the initial request to Freshdesk from your site as the logged in user so it is only in the access token (after approval) that you would be sending the user id to Freshdesk. Freshdesk then makes a request to your userinfo URL for the user details.

Comment: Awesome. This is coming along well. I am sending state to the Freshdesk login, and when I click link (1) Freshdesk successfully hits my app endpoint, sending the state back for verification.

Comment: could you take a look at this related issue I just posted to SO? I'm getting a CORS error calling the Freshdesk redirect_uri. :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66129115/freshdesk-oauth-sso-cors-error-on-accessing-freshdesk-redirect-uri