# Freshdesk Oauth SSO: CORS Error on Accessing Freshdesk Redirect URI?

Tags: javascript, oauth, single-sign-on, freshdesk

I'm setting up OAuth SSO for Freshdesk.  I want the user of my app to be able to login to my Freshdesk support site, without having to create a new username/password.

So far the following steps work:

- My site user clicks a "Support" menu item
- The Freshdesk SSO login page comes up
- My user clicks "client login" there
- Freshdesk hits my Authorization URL with a GET request which my app handles correctly
- Freshdesk hits my same Authorization URL an OPTIONS request which I don't do anything with (other than calling `next()`)
- Freshdesk hits my same Authorization URL with a POST request containing a `redirect_uri`

This is when I get into trouble. My server needs to send some info to the `redirect_uri` provided by Freshdesk, and I get a CORS error.

Here's my server code:

```
    const clientId = req.body.client_id;
    const code = Random.secret();

    const q = new URLSearchParams({
        code: code,
        user: user._id,
        state: req.body.state
    })

    const finalRedirectUri = `${req.body.redirect_uri}?${q}`
    console.info(finalRedirectUri)
    const headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
    res.writeHead(302, { headers, Location: finalRedirectUri})
    res.end()
```

Here's the error message:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: This is just the first thing that came to mind: are you testing from localhost? If so (and you haven't already) it might be an idea to try a tunnel using https://ngrok.com/. That way you can expose your local servers to the internet and that might avoid the issue.

Comment: I'm using something comparable to ngrok -- pagekite. So Freshdesk does successfully reach my Authorization URL with a post request. Hmmmm... so you didn't get a CORS error here? Interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there was a bug on the Freshdesk side in the setup for my account. Theory: when I first created my Freshdesk account, I used the default URLs. Later I asked to change them to reflect my app name and Freshdesk made changes. It may be possible that they missed updating some configs at that time.

I've moved on to a different Help Desk that is more suitable for my app.